# Radius of convergence of complex series $\sum^\infty_{n=10}\frac{n}{2}(z-1)^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of the following complex series:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=10}n(z-1)^{2n}$$

---

I've started by rewriting the above series as follows : $$\sum^\infty_{n=20}\frac{n}{2}(z-1)^{n}$$

This makes it a bit clearer that the radius of convergence $R$  can be found using :

$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty }\sup{\sqrt[n]{a_n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty }{\sup \left ({\frac{n}{2}}\right)^\frac{1}{n}} $$

So, the problem is reduced to evaluating the above limit superior. How do I proceed to evaluate this limit?

---

**Some thoughts**

- I'm under the impression that **squeeze theorem** could be useful
  here.
- Aiming for the above, could I use some inequality between $\lim\sup{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}$ and $\lim{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}?$

Comment: The $10$ and $20$ are not important, since they only affect a finite number of finite terms.  Could you answer the question for $\frac12 \sum n w^n$ or  $\sum n w^n$ with $w$ complex?  Then consider $w=z-1$?

Comment: It is false that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=10}^\infty n(z-1)^{2n}=\sum_{n=20}^\infty\frac n2(z-1)^n$.

Comment: With the reduction advized by Henry, factor $w$, then recognize the derivative of a geometric series for which there exists a closed form formula.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you elaborate on that a bit? I've used this index change more times than I can count in my courses. I'm sure there was a reason I was allowed to do it, which is obviously not true here.

Comment: Are you asking me why could you do it whenever you have done it? How can I know the answer to that question? All I can do is to tell you why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No no, of course you can't. I'd like to know for this case. And thanks for pointing it out as I would keep using it.

Comment: Because$$\sum_{n=10}^\infty n(z-1)^{2n}=10(z-1)^{20}+11(z-1)^{22}+12(z-1)^{24}+\cdots$$whereas$$\sum_{n=20}^\infty\frac n2(z-1)^n=10(z-1)^{20}+\frac{21}2(z-1)^{21}+11(z-1)^{22}+\cdots$$